# Java - Read a list of categories from a file

Tags: java, arrays, string, file

I have multiple .txt file(s) with different amounts of fruits in different categories. An example is this:

```
General Fruits: 
apple
orange
grape
Specific Fruits x:
0: dragon fruit
1: lychee
2: star fruit
3: pomegranate
Specific Fruits y:
0: coconut
1: durian
```

Assuming can I read the file and store apple, orange, grape into a generalFruit[] string array, store dragon fruit, lychee, star fruit, pomegranate into a specificFruitX[] string array, store coconut, durian into a specificFruitsY[] string array?

So far, I have:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString()))) {
  String line;
  String [] generalFruit = new String[50];
  String [] specificFruitX = new String[50];
  String [] specificFruitY = new String[50];
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     // process the line.
     System.out.println(line);                   
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of making a new array with 50 (because you may end up with more than 50) just append each item you read in the file to the array. I'm not sure if this is exact, but generalFruit.append(line); and do that with all the arrays to add each line you read.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah obviously you can do that,

What you need to follow below steps and you will do it.

-1 In while loop check if You have `if(line.equals("General Fruits:"))`
-2 If above condition is true make a boolean which turns On now.
-3 Now see if that boolean is on put the next string in Array `generalFruit[]`

Its really easy you can do it !!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many easy ways to read files and set values into Lists, I always use *.properties files to show static combos normally, if you want to read that file to show many lists, you need to create something like this:

```
List<String> generalFruits = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> specificFruitX = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> specificFruitY = new ArrayList<String>();
```

When you use ArrayList, you have dynamic size of arrays, Is not a good practice set static sizes (50) to your lists, because your files may have many and many rows with fruits and if you have more than 50, you will get and exception.

Then, as you read the file, create objects inside the list, for example:

```
generalFruits.add(new String(line));
```

You have to do the same for each list you want to show in your app.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code, I have made it work to read just General Fruits.
You can work on rest by understanding it.

```
String [] generalFruit = new String[4];
boolean generalFruitboolean=false;
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"))) {
    String line;
    int i=0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if(line.equals("General Fruits:") == true){
            generalFruitboolean=true;
            i=0;

        }

        if(generalFruitboolean==true && i<4){


            generalFruit[i]=line;
            i++;
        }

    }


    for (int j = 0; j < generalFruit.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(generalFruit[j]);
    }
}
```

Hope it will be helpful. best of luck